# Antrl lexer/parser exception understanding

Tags: antlr

I have the following language i wish to parse using antlr 1.2.2.

```
TEST <name>
{
   <param_name> = <param value>;
}
```

while
<...> - means user value, not part of the language keywords

for example

```
TEST myTest
{
   my_param = 1.0;
}
```

the value can be an integer, a real or a quated string
`my_param = 1.0;`, `my_param = 1;` and `my_param = "myStringValue";` are all valid inputs.

here is the grammer for this parsing.

```
parse_test  : TESTKEYWORD TEST_NAME '{' param_value_def '}';
param_value_def : ID EQUALS param_value ';';
param_value : REAL|INTEGER|QUOTED_STRING;


TESTKEYWORD : 'TEST';

QUOTED_STRING   :  '"' ~('"')* '"';

INTEGER     :  MINUS? DIGIT DIGIT*

REAL        :  INTEGER '.' DIGIT DIGIT*;

EQUALS      : '=';

fragment
MINUS       : '-';

fragment
DIGIT       : '0'..'9';
```

when i feed the sample input to the antlr interpreter, i get a `MismatchedTokenException' related to the param_value rule.

can you help me cipher the error message and what i am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: It's impossible to tell what went wrong since the grammar you posted misses rules, and you didn't account for white spaces (and line breaks), and there's a semi-colon missing after the `INTEGER` rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although ANTLRWorks is not a tool well written, you can use its debugger to see which token in the input leads to this exception, and then you can see which rules need to be revised (since you did not post the full grammar).

http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html

Comment: Even though your answer didn't provide a direct answer and is something i new already. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I used portion of your grammar to test, but could not reproduce the exception. So next time you may post more information (at least should help others to reproduce the issue).